# Confidence intervals: What does the histogram of sample means have to do with the true population mean?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, confidence-interval, inference, population

I believe the interpretation of a 95% confidence interval is the following: in 95% of random samples, the true population mean is within 2 standard errors of the sample mean.

The 95% number comes from the normal distribution: in a normal distribution, 95% of the data lies within 2 standard errors of the mean.

I think the normal distribution in this context is referring to the histogram of sample averages, i.e. the histogram that forms when one repeatedly samples the population and plots the averages. The central limit theorem tells us that when a large number of samples are taken, this histogram approximates a normal curve.

However, I don’t understand how the histogram of sample averages is relevant here in the first place. Why does the histogram of *sample* averages come into play while we are making a statement about the *population* parameter?

I am just not seeing the connection. Any help is appreciated. And please feel free to correct any other errors I may have in my understanding.

Comment: Your initial interpretation is incorrect.  In fact, it doesn't make much sense: if you want to characterize a confidence interval, you needn't refer to standard errors.  *In 95% of random samples, the CI covers the mean.*  The 95% doesn't have anything to do with Normality: that's a value *you* specify to meet your decision objectives.  Finally, since the CI is based on a sample and typically is constructed relative to the *sample average,* why shouldn't a histogram of sample averages be relevant?

Comment: Thanks for the response. Perhaps I need to read up on CIs from a different source.  What exactly do you mean when you say that the 95% is something you specify? We can change what percent we're looking for, but that would make the intervals smaller or bigger, right? How do we quantify how much smaller or bigger the intervals become without using the normal curve?

Comment: Here is a [list of the better posts on CV about confidence intervals.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/confidence-interval?tab=Votes) Some of these address your questions.